# prove $\mathbf{R}$ is a partial ordering of $N^{+}$.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let R be the relation on $N^{+}$ defined by x$\mathbf{R}$y if and
only if there is z ∈ $N^{+}$ such that xz = y. Then $\mathbf{R}$ is a partial ordering of  $N^{+}$.

I tried to prove this. I attempted to prove by exhaustion, list out all the cases to state that it satisfies the equivalence relationship.

I also tried to prove by contradiction, to state that it is not true, then list all cases that satisfy the equivalence relationship.

Which is more efficient and is there a better way?

Comment: Use a direct proof.  Look at the definition of partial order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition. You need to show that R is reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive.

1. Reflexive: Pretty obvious, just choose $z=1$.
2. Antisymmetry: a**R**b $\implies$ $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}:a*n=b$

   and b**R**a $\implies$ $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}:b*m=a$

   $\implies m=1/n \implies m=n=1 \implies a=b$
3. Transitivity: a**R**b $\implies$ $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}:a*n=b$

   and b**R**c $\implies$ $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}:b*m=c$

   $\implies a*(n*m)=c \implies$ a**R**c

Comment: It is usually in bad taste to refer to division in a proof strictly about integers.  Recommend rephrasing the antisymmetry argument instead as $a\cdot n=b$ and $b\cdot m=a$ implies $a=a\cdot m\cdot n$ which further implies...